# For row in reader only reading one line

Tags: python

If I am not mistaken, `for`/`in` reads an entire file. But only the first line is read from the file. This is part of a login program and everything else works perfectly and has been tested. How do I make it so that the reader reads all of the lines?

```
 def User1Login():
     while True:
         user_name1 = input ("Player 1 Enter Your Username: ")
         password1 = input ("Player 1 Enter Your Password: ")
         outputs = (user_name1, password1)

         with open ('users.csv',newline='') as f:
             reader = csv.reader(f)
             filenames = ['password','name']
             for row in reader:
                 if user_name1== (row[0]) and password1 == (row[1]):
                     print("User 1 Authorised")
                     return
                 elif user_name1!=(row[0]) and password1!=(row[1]):
                     ("User 1 Unauthorised")
                     break
```

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. _But only the first line is read from the file._ How do you know?

Comment: When running the program, when using the username and password written in the first line of the csv file it authorises the user and continues the code. However, when using the username and password from any other line, it doesn't authorise and loops back for the username and password again. Changing the username and password from any given line that doesn't work (anything but line 1) to line 1 then works. So, I know it is only reading line one.

Comment: _it doesn't authorise and loops back for the username and password again._ Isn't that to be expected? If the user name and password are both different from those on the first line (or any, for that matter), your code breaks out of the for loop, right?

Comment: As an aside, the presence of the number _1_ in your function and variable names is probably not a good sign, be careful.

Comment: If the user inputs "user1" for the username and "password1" for the password and somewhere in the csv file there is a line that says " user1,password1 ", it should authorise as that user exists.

Comment: Is _If the user inputs "user1" for the username and "password1" for the password and somewhere in the csv file there is a line that says " user1,password1 ", it should authorise as that user exists_ in response to my comment?

Comment: yes sorry, should've clarified.

Comment: The `elif` suite [`break`s](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) out of the for loop. You should probably use `continue` instead of `break` if you want to run through all the users.

Comment: @ParadoxIan To which one of my comments, though?

Comment: By the way, if you can provide more context/information for what this function is meant to do, I can try to rewrite it.

Comment: @wwii using continue does read the rest of the file, but reads and prints all the users it reads as unauthorised until finding the matching username and password

Comment: @AMC yeah thanks. I was responding to your "Isn't that to be expected?". This function is meant to read from a csv file with all the username and passwords that people have created from another function that writes it in the format of " username,password ". If there is a matching username and password it *logs them in*, so that there game score can be recorded with their name. If there isn't then they need to create one.

Comment: @ParadoxIan How is called? Why have it return nothing, and just print a value? There has to be a way to generalize the function and make it more robust, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unauthorized conditional does not look right.

A user should be considered unauthorized if the username matches and the password does not.

Conisder this example

```
username=hello
password=world
```

users.csv

```
username|password
a,b
c,d
hello,world
```

`hello != a` and `world !=b`

Code will break out of loop at first line, not reading the rest of the csv. You should edit the else-if suite.

```
 def User1Login():
     while True:
         user_name1 = input ("Player 1 Enter Your Username: ")
         password1 = input ("Player 1 Enter Your Password: ") 

         outputs = (user_name1, password1) 
         with open ('users.csv',newline='') as f:
             reader = csv.reader(f) 
             filenames = ['password','name'] 

             for row in reader: 
                 if user_name1== (row[0]) and password1 == (row[1]):

                     print("User 1 Authorised") 
                     return

                 elif user_name1==(row[0]) and password1!=(row[1]):

                     ("User 1 Unauthorised")
                     break
```

Comment: After changing the != to just a " else " , it still only reads the first line.

Comment: Setting the second conditional to a general else is not correct because you break immediately

Comment: Have checked if it works and it runs perfectly. Thanks!